# sensenet: installation error (microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser version=13.0.0.0' could not be loaded)

Tags: sensenet

I am new to `sensenet`. I am trying to install `sensenet` version `sn-community-webpi-6.5.4.9243.zip` by importing this zip using Web deploy in `IIS`. But in installation wizard I am getting following error and it gets aborted.

```
The assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser version=13.0.0.0' could not be loaded.
could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser version=13.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

That dll is not related to Sense/Net. According to this post, there is a possibility that something is missing around *SQL Server Shared Management Objects*, because this library is part of that package. Maybe this is a 32/64 bit issue with your Windows and/or SQL Server installation.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4d682289-9e06-4dd3-aff3-d08ad437896d/file-or-assembly-microsoftsqlserverbatchparser-error?forum=sqldatabaseengine

You may try to (re)install SMO for your SQL Server version. I haven't tried these links, just did a quick search:

SQL Server 2012:

- http://www.thesqlreport.com/?p=675
- https://netlibsecurity.com/kb/kb-240112-installing-sql-server-shared-management-objects-sql-smo/

SQL Server 2014:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295

SQL Server 2016:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162189.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396